# How to Bold and Italic a particular word throughout the document in latex?

Tags: bold, italic

I need to use Bold or Italic a particular word through my latex document, where ever it is used, without explicitly mentioning `textbf{}` and `textit{}` on each of them. How can I do that?

A good analogy would be, CSS to HTML tags.

Is it possible to this in Latex?

Comment: `\newcommand{\mystrangeword}{\textbf{particularword}\xspace}`  for example, use `\mystrangeword` then. -- and yes, `\xspace` has its issues ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is `\mymarkup` in a starred and unstarred variant. The unstarred variant gives `\textbf{...}` and the starred one is responsible for italic version. The double starred version gives **bold** and *italic* and the optional parameter changes the text:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mymarkup}{ssO{myword}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      {\bfseries\itshape #3}%
    }{%
      \textit{#3}%
    }%
  }{%
    \textbf{#3}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\mymarkup\ is better than \mymarkup*\, which is followed by \mymarkup**\ again

\mymarkup[Don't use xspace]\ is better than \mymarkup*[Don't use xspace]\, which is followed by \mymarkup**[Don't use xspace]\ again


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If it's a similar word each time you can create a command:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\textbf{foo}\xspace}
```

Another solution is to create shorter tag for `\textbf` or `\textit`:

```
\newcommand{\tit}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\tbf}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

Those solutions suppose that you have no particular command called the same way or an error will be raised.

Comment: `\xspace`... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer keyboard doesn't want to work all the time `;-)`

Comment: `\i` and `\b` are defined commands already

Comment: Oh no! An xspace!

Comment: @yo' A wild `xspace` appears. `xspace` used `\xspace`, it’s super effective!

Answer (score 6):

Just for variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Note that it doesn't require you to modify the body of the document in any way. The word to be rendered in bold-italics throughout the document should be listed as the second argument of the `string.gsub` function.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function highlight_word ( line )
   return string.gsub ( line, "myparticularword", "{\\bfseries\\itshape %0}" )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", highlight_word, "highlight_word" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
An interesting story about myparticularword and its history \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're into lua recently, hm??? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Yup, you got me pegged...

Comment: I got you pegged? What have I done? :D